# find if string1 is contained in string2 in python

Tags: python

I have two strings: `string1 = ABCDE` and `string2 = BC`.

I hope to write a program returning a T/F value for whether string2 is contained in string1. For the example above, the function should return True. I know it's something like the `%in%` function in `R`, but since I am a newbie in Python, please share your thoughts on this simple question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def StringTest(string1, string2):
  return string2 in string1
```

Or outside of a function:

```
result = string2 in string1
```

Either of these will return a boolean result.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know the `in` operator in Python...that's indeed very convenient.

Comment: @alittleboy No worries - it is definitely a good one to know :)

Comment: @Ant Haha, yeah - I misread it at first and through 'program' said 'function'.

Answer (score 1):

```
if string1 in string2: print "YES!"
```

this is really easy in python ;)

Comment: technically, he wanted to know if string2 is in string1, so: Wrong! :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
string2.find(string1) != -1
```

would also work.